# Por que quando faço duas operações com números inteiros e guardo o resultado em um double ele me dá de retorno um 0,0?

Tags: java, tipagem, matemática

Exemplo:

```
double teste = 673/5455 * 100;

System.out.println(teste);
```

Ele imprime 0.0 sendo que não é esse o resultado da conta... por que isso acontece?

Comment: Quanto é o inteiro 673 dividido pelo inteiro 5455?

Comment: Então precisa voltar aprender matemática.

Comment: Não liga Aline.

Comment: ...okay Fábio =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como a própria pergunta já diz está dividindo dois inteiros, portanto o resultado será um inteiro. Se dividir 673 por 5455 obviamente dará um valor inferior a 1 já que o divisor é maior que o dividendo, na verdade ficará abaixo de 0,5 e como ele só pode trabalhar com inteiro ele arredonda para 0, depois multiplicando por 100 continua dando 0 e guarda o 0 na variável.

Se quer resolver faça que um deles seja `double`, por exemplo `673.0`.

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        double teste = 673.0 / 5455 * 100;
        System.out.println(teste);  
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JpoacG). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rbiqczlm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/DoubleDivision.java).

Comment: hummmm. Eu já sabia resolver isso só não entendia porque isso acontecia agora vc explicou. Assim tbm vai: double teste =(double)  673/5455 * 100;

Comment: Agora eu entendi!!!

Comment: Sim, o cast funciona, mas já colocar o literal correto é melhor